# Overloading problem: Cannot resolve method

Tags: java, swagger

I have generic type Schema and a lot of inherited classes like: StringSchema, IntegerSchema etc

```
public class Schema<T> { }
public class StringSchema extends Schema<String> { }
```

When I try get class from schema and call overloading setDefaultValues method I get this error:

> Cannot resolve method 'setDefaultValues(java.lang.Class<capture<?
> extends io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema>>)'

```
private <T> void defineSchemaAndValues(Schema<T> schema) {
    setDefaultValues(schema.getClass());
}

private void setDefaultValues(StringSchema schema) {
    schema.setMaxLength(100);
}

private void setDefaultValues(IntegerSchema schema) {
    schema.setMaxLength(200);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to present the code as *text* rather than as screenshots. Screenshots are harder to read, can't be searched, and can't be copy/pasted.

Comment: You also haven't shown the `Schema` generic class declaration... basically we're missing a lot of context here. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ehm, ok ... you are passing an instance of Class, not an instance of StringSchema, nor of IntegerSchema. How did you assume that would work?

Comment: Do not post code as image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for the reson.

Comment: Overloading is determined at compile-time. The JVM cannot just decide what method to call at runtime. Also, `getClass()` gets an object representing a class, not the object as the actual class.

Comment: This looks like you want the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), maybe take a look.

Comment: @Stultuske I will add the instance as the second argument

Comment: why as second? why not as only?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. The code confuses casting with getting a `Class` instance. Instead of an object of type `IntegerSchema` (which seems to be expected) there is an object of type `Class`, which is a metamodel for all `IntegerSchema` objects.
2. The whole design is built the design around hope that overloading in Java is dynamic - so that you can choose at runtime which method is going to be called. However, it does not work like that - the call is resolved statically.